# Datafactory to sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, azure-data-factory

I've setup a connection from our data factory in azure to a sharepoint site so I can pull some of the lists on the site into blob storage so I can then process into our warehouse. This all works fine and I can see the data I want. I don't however want to pull all the columns contained in the list I'm after. Looking at the connection I can specify a query, however anything I put in here has no affect on the data that comes back. Is there a way to specify the columns from a list in sharepoint through the copy activity into blob storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to user select query like below -
`$select=Title,Number,OrderDate` in the Query text field of the Azure Data Factory Source.
You could use **Preview Data** button to validate the results.  Please refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sharepoint-online-list#sharepoint-online-list-as-source) for using Custom OData query options.

I have tried this and it works fine for me (see screenshot below)-

[image]

Thanks
Saurabh